# strange crash between different library

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, windows-vista

I have a old application develop on c++ with Microsoft Visual Studio 6!
This application called a c++ DLL (develop with Microsoft Visual Studio 6).

Old version: [APPLICATION (VS6)] <-> [c++ DLL (VS6) Version1]

For a new feature I develop a new library on C# (for call a web service, develop with Visual Studio 2010 with Windows 7) and a library wrapper on c++ (develop with Visual Studio 2010 with Windows 7).

New version: [APPLICATION (VS6)] <-> [c++ DLL (VS6) Version2] <-> [c++ wrapper (VS 2010)] <-> [c# (VS 2010)]

I have installed:

- Microsoft Visual c++ 2005 Redistributable SP1
- Microsoft Visual c++ 2010 Redistributable SP1
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Client

Use "gacutil /i" for .NET C# Library

I have execute this procedure for all my PC but only some pc don't work fine.

When I change the [c++ DLL (VS6) Version1] on [c++ DLL (VS6) Version2] I have a problem with some pc.
I installed this solution on several PCs, but for some, the program crashes (on windows Vista).
For now I analyzed two computers and they give me different errors:

1. faulting module MSVBVM60.dll
2. faulting module SYSFER.DLL

Where I wrong?
I need some other package to be installed (runtime)?

Thank you

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------

I changed the library for reduced the problem!

New version: [APPLICATION (VS6)] <-> [c++ DLL (VS6) Version2] <-> [c++ wrapper (VS 2010)]

The problem is always:

- faulting module SYSFER.DLL_unloaded

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------

On console I launched this command: sc config sysplant start= disabled

and now the error is changed:

- faulting module VERSION.dll_unloaded

Do you have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: That's the runtime support module for VB6 apps.  Sysfer.dll is Symantec anti-malware stuff.  Clearly there are a lot more moving parts than you counted on.  You can't reasonably expect help with that here.  Realistically, you'll need to cut off some heads off this multi-headed monster to get somewhere comfortable.

Comment: Hi, I reduced the uncertainty but I still have problems I can not solve!

Answer (score 1):

Sysfer.dll is a Symantec Antivirus dll that is injected into every application ran on that machine (this was added with SEP 12.1). Some older legacy apps are not compatible with it and crash when they are run. This is not an issue with your c++ libraries, it's an issue with Symantec.

The good news is, you can create exceptions in symantec to allow your old legacy app to run. Follow [this link](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=HOWTO95454) to learn more. The other option is to uninstall Symantec Antivirus, but depending on your computer/client this may not be an option. Good luck!